# Handle notifications in background service or use GCM(or other push notification service)

Tags: java, android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an app which receives data from server and if the data has some value, it will show some notification to user (DANGER STATUS or etc).

I read this : [Android Notification: GCM or Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238870/android-notification-gcm-or-service) which says that GCM is much better than handling Notification in background-services. But as far as I know GCM also needs implementing background services(in app) to work. So what is the difference?

Is using GCM really more optimized than handling notification in background service? Both are background service...so why are they different?

Also GCM doesn't show the notification sometimes, and it's not 
reliable.... this is why I'm thinking to implement notification in background-service.

What is the best way?

Comment: Firstly read the difference between Service  and intent service and read about the gcm functionality http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha the link you mentioned is exactly the example which a have implemented before! i think im a little bit confused